# How to call a function only after getting response from restcall node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have one request.post call and another function.Where I need to pass the response of restcall as paramaters to the function.

The current issue which Iam facing here is that the function is getting called even before i get response from the rest call and null values are getting passed.I know that we need to use some callabcks for this issue.But I dont know how to do it.can someone help.

```
app.post('/verifycreds',function(req,res) {
  var reqdata = req.body;
  var data = {};
  data.custid = reqdata.custid;
  request.post({
    url:'https://database.mybluemix.net/verifycredentials',
    headers:{
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    body:data,
    json:true
}, function(err,response) {
  verifycreds(response.body);  
});

function verifycreds(data) {
  if((datareq.customerid === data.customerid ) && (datareq.password == data.password)){
    res.send("valid");
  } else {
    res.send("invalid");
  }
}
```

So how can I call verifycreds function only after I get response from the request .post call..Any help!

Comment: What's `request`? What's the signature of `request.post`?

Comment: This situation happens to me sometimes, when you saw that your code is absolute correct but the output is not like the expectation then my question is "How you know the callback function was run before" ?

Comment: @thelonglqd I kept a console in my verifycreds and I can see that data is null

Comment: @thelonglqd It is working now.My bad

Comment: Yes, inspect thoroughly before asking here because making question here is more time consuming and distraction than double checking your/my own code (lol)

Answer (score 3):

Your callback is valid, the problem in callback parameters. It should be defined with three parameters:

- error
- response
- body

So correct code is:

```
request.post({
 url: 'https://database.mybluemix.net/verifycredentials',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 body: data,
 json: true
}, function(err, res, body) {
  // TODO: process possible errors
  // if (err) { ...
  verifycreds(body);  
});
```

Comment: Why would that cause the reported symptom? *"The current issue which Iam facing here is that the function is getting called even before i get response from the rest call..."*

Comment: Author mentioned, that callback is calling with `null`, it's because it's not in the response, but in own parameter,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my hunch is that's not true, but assumed because the callback was receiving null.

Comment: @alexmac Still getting the same issue..verifycreds function is getting null values

Comment: response is not the issue here..Iam getting that..But verifycreds is getting null value..I may need to use some kind of callback

Comment: @user7350714 are you sure that your request to `https://database.mybluemix.net/verifycredentials` is valid and contains a body? Could you test in postman for example.

Comment: @user7350714 Could you accept this answer please, if it solved your problem?